# google map api v2

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've problem calling gdrirection.load(),if I specified the values it'll work ,but if I pass them through text boxes it doesn't work.
here's my code

```
var map;
    var directionsPanel;
    var directions;
function initialize() {

        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
            map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(24.7116667, 46.7241667), 12);
            map.setUIToDefault();
            var txtAddress = document.getElementById('txtAddress').value;
            var TextBox1 = document.getElementById('TextBox1').value;
            directions = new GDirections(map, directionsPanel);
            directions.load("from: 'TextBox1' to: 'txtAddress'");        
        } 
    }
<body onload=initialize()>

            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" Visible="true" />
            <input type="button" value="direction" onclick="initialize();" title="direction"  />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:TextBox>`
```

Thanks

Comment: Note [google maps v2 is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/)

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are passing `TextBox1` as from address and `txtAddress` as to address. So google is not able to understand the both address.Use the following code to pass values from textboxes:

```
directions.load("from: "+TextBox1+" to: "+txtAddress+"");
```

This one will work fine.Hope this helps you :-)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I changed the code a bit ,but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Here is the code                                                  `var txtAddress = document.getElementById("<%=txtAddress.ClientID %>");
            
            var address = txtAddress.value;

            var TextBox1 = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>");
            
            var address1 = TextBox1.value;  
            
            directions = new GDirections(map, directionsPanel);
            directions.load("from: " + TextBox1 + " to: " + txtAddress + "");`

Comment: once check whether you are getting the values into address and address1 vatiables?